# How can I append to a memoryStream in a foreach loop without overwriting it's contents?

Tags: c#, stream, memorystream

I'm currently making api calls that return MemoryStream objects. I'm having issues iterating through a for loop and appending a memory stream to another using the copyTo method. It overwrites what was already in the stream.

I've tried almost every combination of stack overflow answers thus far and haven't been able to get the proper result.

```
                MemoryStream docStream2 = new MemoryStream();
                MemoryStream docStream3 = new MemoryStream();

                docStream = (MemoryStream)ApiCall
                docStream2 = (MemoryStream)ApiCall
                docStream3 = (MemoryStream)ApiCall

                docStream.Position = 0;
                docStream2.Position = 0;
                docStream2.CopyTo(docStream);
                docStream.Position = docStream.Length;
                docStream3.Position = 0;
                docStream3.CopyTo(docStream);

                return docStream
```

I am expecting to get a stream that has all of the contents of each docStream memoryStream object. Instead I only get the last stream. Also I thought about making a list of streams but I haven't found out a way to return a list of streams from webapi2 to a mvc4 application, but this is a side issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming that `docStream` is empty, you don't need to move its position: when you `CopyTo` it, the current position will be set to the end of the stream. BUT `docStream` needs to be empty when you begin copying the content of other streams. So, use a brand new `MemoryStream` and your code will work as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [WriteTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.writeto?view=netframework-4.7.2), as you don't need to worry about the reading streams position.

Knowing that, all you need to do make sure the result stream position is where you want it (the end).

Consider this test app:

```
// Create some data
var stuff = Enumerable.Range(0, 15)
                        .Select(x => (byte)x)
                        .ToArray();

// Create some streams
var ms1 = new MemoryStream();
var ms2 = new MemoryStream();
var ms3 = new MemoryStream();

// write some data to the streams for a test
ms1.Write(stuff, 0, 5);
ms2.Write(stuff, 5, 5);
ms3.Write(stuff, 10, 5);

// make sure we are at the end of the result stream
ms1.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

// write the other streams to the result
ms2.WriteTo(ms1);
ms3.WriteTo(ms1);

// test it's working
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", ms1.ToArray()));
```

**Output**

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
```